# Excel Interop to open excel with macros disabled

Tags: .net, excel, interop, com-interop

Is there a way in C# to switch off macros in excel before loading an excel file. I am loading the excel file using Excel Interop. All I can see is solutions for VB.NET.

Thanks 
 Nishant

Comment: A solution in VB.NET should be trivial to port to C# - can you post an example and someone will translate it very quickly I'm sure.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you can just set it on your Excel Application:

```
Excel.Application xapp = new Excel.Application();
xapp.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
```